# Custom Directive to replicate VB .net functionality For matching names in datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, api

I am new to angularjs and Web API although i have worked in VB.NET Desktop Applications. 
I have a function that matches all the available results in my data source (from left to right).
 The code for the function is

```
 Public Sub Combo_KeyUp(ByVal cmb As ComboBox, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    Dim TypText As String
    Dim IFoundI As Integer
    Dim oFoundItem As Object
    Dim sFoundText As String
    Dim sAppendText As String
    Select Case e.KeyCode
        Case Keys.Back, Keys.Left, Keys.Right, Keys.Up, Keys.Delete, Keys.Down, Keys.Enter, Keys.Tab
            Return
    End Select
    TypText = cmb.Text
    IFoundI = cmb.FindString(TypText)
    If IFoundI >= 0 Then
        oFoundItem = cmb.Items(IFoundI)
        sFoundText = cmb.GetItemText(oFoundItem)
        sAppendText = sFoundText.Substring(TypText.Length)
        cmb.Text = TypText & sAppendText
        cmb.SelectionStart = TypText.Length
        cmb.SelectionLength = sAppendText.Length
    End If

End Sub
```

What i need to do is perform the same functionality with Angularjs Web API. Some of the functionality  by directive but it does not match from left to right it shows all the results having that particular string.